# Сравнение целой и дробной части в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно сделать так, чтобы первые две цифры в дробной части заданного float числа совпадали с записью целой части этого числа. Например:
15.155441514 - True.
15.141541451 - False

Попробовал так:

```
a = input("Введите вещественное число: ").split('.')
if (a[0]) == (a[1][0] and a[1][1]):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Но оно выдаёт цифры через пробел и выдаёт False.

Comment: `print(x := 15.15467, x // 1 == x % 1 * 100 // 1)`

Comment: Благодарю за код

Comment: @Fofan235 вы неправильно строите условие для `if`. если `a[0]`-цифры до запятой, то первые две цифры после запятой `a[1][:2]` значит  `if a[0] ==a[1][:2]:`

Comment: Какой же я глупый), вот за это объяснение миллион благодарностей!

Comment: @Namerek, не работает: `print(x := 11.11, x // 1 == x % 1 * 100 // 1)` -> `11.11 False`. Я хочу сказать что эту задачу трудно решить хорошо, если работать с числами. Если вводимую строку не переводить в число, задача решается проще.

Comment: Еще кстати, любопытно - а `1.01` - это  как, True или False?

Answer (score 0):

В записи которую вы указали в `if`, у вас происходит проверка так: целая часть проверяется на равенство с первой и второй цифрами дробной части по отдельности, а не как с единым целым, то есть `True` будет выдавать только если целая часть это одна цифра и только тогда когда целая часть (одна цифра) равна первой цифре дробной и второй цифре дробной, пример:

```
1.11 -> 1 = 1 = 1 -> True
1.21 -> 1 != 2 = 1 -> False
2.23 -> 2 = 2 != 3 -> False
33.33 -> 33 != 3 != 3 -> False
```

Вот как можно это исправить:

```py
a = input("Введите вещественное число: ").split('.')
if a[0] == a[1][:2]:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

В данной конструкции используется срез первых двух цифр дробной части, потом этот срез сравнивается с целой частью и печатается результат.

Comment: `В записи которую вы указали в if, у вас происходит проверка так: целая часть проверяется на равенство с первой и второй цифрами дробной части ` - это не так: a[0] проверяется на равенство с логическим and первой и второй цифры после запятой

Comment: я это и хотел сказать @splash58

Comment: но не получилось